# A tag link not converting inside TextView - Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I have a ListView and I'm trying to convert an HTML link tag to be clickable w/ a TextView.. I do not know what I'm doing wrong?  It doesn't convert this:

```
String txt = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
viewHolder.txtMessage.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
viewHolder.txtMessage.setClickable(true);
viewHolder.txtMessage.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt));
```

Additionally here's what the XML looks like:

```
<TextView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:linksClickable="true"
 android:autoLink="web"
 android:textColorLink="#fff"
 android:text=""
 android:textIsSelectable="true"
 android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
 android:textColor="@android:color/white"
 android:textSize="16dp" />
```

*Edit*

It's not the same as the other SO question.  Their solution does not work w/ my use-case.  My question is referring to getting the link to convert, while that question is refers to non-a tag html links.  I do not know if it being in a listview has anything to do with it.

Comment: What do you see when you run this code? Is it Google or entire string?

Comment: The same code is working perfectly for me. I am not using .setClickable(true).

Comment: Is this being set inside a TextView inside a ListView?

Comment: This seems to be a known [issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0CuadQTDj_k). Perhaps try a Recyclerview?